# How to get all combinations of a list?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I know that I can use `itertools.permutation` to get all permutations of size r.

But, for `itertools.permutation([1,2,3,4],3)` it will return `(1,2,3)` as well as `(1,3,2)`.

1. I want to filter those repetitions (i.e obtain combinations)
2. Is there a simple way to get all permutations (of all lengths)?
3. How can I convert `itertools.permutation()` result to a regular list?

Comment: Are you looking for `combinations`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and a simple loop to get combinations of all size.

`combinations` return an iterator so you've to pass it to `list()` to see it's content(or consume it).

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in xrange(1, len(lis) + 1):  #  xrange will return the values 1,2,3,4 in this loop
    print list(combinations(lis, i))
...     
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
[(1,2,3,4)]
```

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you are actually looking for [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

This example also shows how to convert the result to a regular list, just pass it to the built-in `list()` function.

To get the combinations for each length you can just use a loop like the following:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i in range(1, len(data)+1):
...     print list(combinations(data, i))
... 
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Or to get the result as a nested list you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [list(combinations(data, i)) for i in range(1, len(data)+1)]
[[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)], [(1, 2, 3, 4)]]
```

For a flat list instead of nested:

```
>>> [c for i in range(1, len(data)+1) for c in combinations(data, i)]
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `itertools.combinations()`. And to get a regular list, just use `list()` factory function.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```