# How to create lists of combinations

Tags: python, string, list

I have generated all possible combinations using elements in a list, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176887/python-get-all-permutation-of-a-list-w-o-repetitions). Now, I would like to know how to save each combination as a list.
I get this output:

```
[('A',),
 ('B',),
 ('A','B')
  ......]
```

I would get something like this:

```
[['A'],['B'],['AB'], ...... ]
```

Is there a simple way to implement it?

Comment: First decide if you want each combination as a **list** or as a **string** (`'AB'` is a string, while `['A', 'B']` is a list of two strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map` like so:

```
combinations = [('A',),
                ('B',),
                ('A','B')]

combinations_list = map(list, combinations)
```

Which would return a `generator` (Python3) or a `list` (Python2). If you want a `list` just cast it to list:

```
combinations_list = list(map(list, combinations))
```

This would convert the inner tuple structure to a list:

```
[("A"), ("B"), ("A", "B")] -> [["A"], ["B"], ["A", "B"]]
```

If you want to also flatten the tuple to get the following result:

```
[("A"), ("B"), ("A", "B")] -> [["A"], ["B"], ["AB"]]
```

You should change the first argument of the `map` for this:

```
lambda sub_tuple: ["".join(sub_tuple)]
```

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns `iterator` object only in **Python 3**, in **Python 2** [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) returns `list` object (while [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) returns iterator)

Comment: You're right, should've pointed it out. I'm getting really used to working only in Python3.

Comment: that's ok, **Python 3** is great

Answer (score 3):

If you're saying you have a list of tuples, and you want a list of lists, you can convert it using

```
list_of_lists = [list(t) for t in list_of_tuples]
```

or you could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

In Python 2:

```
list_of_lists = map(list, list_of_tuples)
```

In Python 3:

```
list_of_lists = list(map(list, list_of_tuples))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176932/2454357) linked by the OP:

```
from itertools import combinations
lis = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
result = []
for i in range(1, len(lis)+1):  

    result+=[''.join(c) for c in combinations(lis, i)]

print(result)
```

gives

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ACD', 'BCD', 'ABCD']
```

**EDIT**:

The same as one-liner:

```
result = [''.join(c) for i in range(1,len(lis)+1) for c in combinations(lis,i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension with `str.join`:

```
>>> combinations = [('A',), ('B',), ('A','B')]
>>> [[''.join(comb)] for comb in combinations]
[['A'], ['B'], ['AB']]
```

Instead of the list-comprehension you could also use a generator expression:

```
>>> combs_as_lists = ([''.join(comb)] for comb in combinations)
>>> for comb in combs_as_lists:
...     print(comb)
['A']
['B']
['AB']
```